# sql package creating error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a code in which i delete a student from my table by specifying his nr_matr, but if i don't have that nr_matr in my table then i want to trow an exception.
this is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE manager_faculty IS
     PROCEDURE delete_stud (nr_matr student.nr_matricol%type);
END manager_faculty;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY manager_faculty IS

    PROCEDURE delete_stud (nr_matr student.nr_matricol%type) IS
    BEGIN
       DELETE from student
         WHERE nr_matricol=nr_matr;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN no_data_found THEN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter FROM student WHERE nr_matricol=nr_matr;
      IF counter = 0 THEN
         raise_application_error (-20001, 'There is no student with the number' || nr_matr);
      END IF;
    END delete_stud;

END manager_faculty;
/

set serveroutput on;
BEGIN
manager_faculty.delete_stud(125);
END;
/
```

When i'm trying to compile my code it says that the package body was created whit compilation errors. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please run `SHOW ERRORS;` after trying to compile the package body and post the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `PLS-00201: identifier 'COUNTER' must be declared` and you can find this out by running `SHOW ERRORS;` after trying to compile your package body.

You can fix it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY manager_faculty IS

    PROCEDURE delete_stud (nr_matr student.nr_matricol%type)
    IS
      counter INT;
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM student
      WHERE nr_matricol=nr_matr;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO   counter
        FROM   student
        WHERE  nr_matricol=nr_matr;

        IF counter = 0 THEN
          raise_application_error (
            -20001,
            'There is no student with the number' || nr_matr
          );
        END IF;
    END delete_stud;
END manager_faculty;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

However, the code won't run as you expect as `DELETE FROM` will not throw an exception if it does not delete any rows. You will need to check `SQL%ROWCOUNT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY manager_faculty IS
  PROCEDURE delete_stud (nr_matr student.nr_matricol%type)
  IS
  BEGIN
    DELETE from student
    WHERE nr_matricol=nr_matr;

    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
      raise_application_error (
        -20001,
        'There is no student with the number' || nr_matr
      );
    END IF;
  END delete_stud;
END manager_faculty;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using SQL%ROWCOUNT as answered by MTO, you can also use SQL%NOTFOUND.

> **%NOTFOUND** yields TRUE if an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement affected no rows, or a SELECT INTO statement returned no rows. Otherwise, it yields FALSE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY manager_faculty IS
   PROCEDURE delete_stud (nr_matr student.nr_matricol%type)
   IS
   BEGIN
      DELETE from student
         WHERE nr_matricol=nr_matr;

      IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        raise_application_error (
           -20001,
           'There is no student with the number' || nr_matr
        );
      END IF;
   END delete_stud;
END manager_faculty;
```

You can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/13_elems48.htm), if you want to know other attributes of SQL Cursor.